# Operator precedence and associativity only determine how expressions are grouped, they do not specify an order of evaluation

Tags: php, operator-precedence

from the PHP documentation:

> Operator precedence and associativity only determine how expressions
>   are grouped, they do not specify an order of evaluation.

it means that this code might give an error?:

```
$a = true || new bla(); // bla class doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no.

The order of evaluation is normal left to right. Not by the precedence/associativity.

It's just grouped like:

```
(true) || (new bla())
```

The statement is just not executed because the first statement is true (short-circuiting); this is specified by the logical-or operator (at run-time)